# HTC One keyboard does not change language, inputType=textVisiblePassword

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a problem with native HTC One keyboard in multilanguage environment.

There is a button on the keyboard which allows to switch the language:
[image: EN/RU Button]

When I enter the text in "plain" EditText this button is enabled, so I can enter text using any language.

However when the inputType=textVisiblePassword is added:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />
```

the change-the-language button becomes disabled:

[image]

Any another keyboard (Swype+Dragon, ...) works ok. 
Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have the same problem. No good options so far - use plain text EditText for passwords, ask user to install Google Keyboard instead of HTC keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think for password fields only english language is supported as you need to validate it with server and so.

Comment: The problem is that any another keyboard works fine, so it seems to be a HTC's bug.

Comment: And passwords are only ever in english?  This is clearly an error.